# Is there any best practice for getting the first character of a string in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

For years I have used `stringname[0]` to obtain the first char of a `string` without even thinking about it. However, I recently came to wonder if brute access to the array is really a good practice. This may seem a trivial question, but it is not because it looks deeply linked to memory/access management of STL containers.

I can think of `stringname.at(0)` (not very convincing) but there are probably better alternatives with an iterator. Most importantly, the ideal method would not cause an error if the string is empty.

Any widely accepted good practice for this ?

Comment: With modern, fast CPUs, and smart, optimizing compilers, it makes no practical difference how you do it. operator[], at(), c_str(), it's all the same thing. As long as you have a non-empty string, of course.

Comment: What do you want to get for an empty string if not an error?

Comment: Okay thank you, I was just wondering if there was some kind of ‘everyone-should-use’ trick I was missing, but apparently there isn’t.

Comment: The "everyone-should-use" trick is to choose the appropriate accessor for the job.  The reason there are several, is because they have different behaviours.  One you didn't mention is `std::string::front`.

Comment: Usually I use `if (!stringname.empty()) firstchar=*stringname.begin();`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `s` is an empty string, `s[0]` returns `'\0'` whereas `s.at(0)` throws `std::out_of_range`.

That difference in *behavior* is far more significant than any difference in performance.

Comment: when the string is empty, `s[0]` is guaranteed to return `'\0'` only if 1) `s` is `const`, or 2) you are using C++11 or later.  Prior to C++11, the behavior of the non-const `operator[]` is undefined for an empty string, but the behavior of the const `operator[]` is defined.  C++11 corrects the non-const behavior.